# A div 100% in body with margins

Tags: css, html, margin, absolute

I have a 'body' with 40px of margin.

Moreover, I want to add a div with 100% in height and 100% in weight with the 'static position'.

My problem is that my 'div' is go beyond the 'body' !
I want my div fills the 'body' (respecting with the margin of it : 40px).

How can I solve this problem ?

Thks

[MY JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w7Z5M/1/)

```
body { 
    background:pink;
    margin:40px;
    }

.contenuWorks {
    height:100%;
    width: 100% ;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    }
```

Comment: Well... could you explain the problem a bit more? If I look at the JS Fiddle it looks exactly like the thing you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Is it important to you that the background of the div not touch the edges of the body?

Comment: @EmeryFramboise I think @Bonjour wants to have a pink border of 40px surrounding the `.countenuWorks` div. Not just on the top and left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use an absolute positioning you can just set coordinates of the div.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EQEPY/

```
.contenuWorks {
    left: 40px;
    right: 40px;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you choose a box-model with `box-sizing`, you can turn the problem into none.

First trigger the box-model with : `box-sizing:border-box;`  http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0 / http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/boxsizing.html

Then turn the margin of body into padding in html.
If you choose : `border-box` it includes border and padding into the size set in CSS.

```
<div>  
    box-sizing and use   
    <code>height: 100%; width : 100%;</code>  
    without headhakes. 
</div>
```

```
html, body, div {
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  border:solid;
  margin:0;  
}
html {
  padding:40px;
  border:solid red;
}
body {
  border:solid blue;
}
div{
  border:solid yellow;
  background:pink;
}
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Fjqzn

Answer (score -1):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sbDSy/2/

Why not apply `padding` to the `div` instead of `margin` to the `body`:

```
.contenuWorks {
    height:100%;
    width: 100% ;
    padding:40px;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
}

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Because that won't work with the content-box box model. http://jsfiddle.net/sbDSy/3/ You've made it too wide. Throw in `padding-box` box model and you have a winner, though. Assuming the OP is OK with the background filling the page.

Comment: what about the use `box-sizing` ?